# Saving array as Geotiff using rasterio

Tags: python, raster, numpy-ndarray, geotiff, rasterio

I have the following numpy array:

```
supervised.shape
(1270, 1847)
```

I am trying to use the following code to save it to GeoTIFF using `rasterio`:

```
with rasterio.open('/my/path/ReferenceRaster.tif') as src:
    ras_meta = src.profile

with rasterio.open('/my/output/path/output_supervised.tif', 'w', **ras_meta) as dst:
    dst.write(supervised)
```

Where `ras_meta` is:

```
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 1847, 'height': 1270, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32736), 'transform': Affine(10.0, 0.0, 653847.1979372115,
       0.0, -10.0, 7807064.5603836905), 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'band'}
```

I am facing the following error which I cannot understand since both the reference raster and my `supervised` array have the same `shape`

```
ValueError: Source shape (1270, 1847) is inconsistent with given indexes 1
```

Any idea what is the issue here? I am not completly understanding the meaning of the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`write` expects an array with shape `(band, row, col)`. You can either reshape your array, or you can use `write(supervised, indexes=1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was already investigating the `np.transpose` option but you answer definetly put me on the right way